# Sharepoint 2013 Upgrade Fails

Tags: upgrade

Hy Everyone!

I'm trying to patch my Sharepoint 2013 farm with the following KBs: KB2863892 - KB2878240.

I run the PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures command after the installation of the KBs.

I get the following error:

```
10.00% : Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.

An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additi
onal exception information: The upgrade command is invalid or a failure has been encountered.
Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.

Total number of configuration settings run: 5
Total number of successful configuration settings: 4
Total number of unsuccessful configuration settings: 1
Successfully stopped the configuration of SharePoint Products.
Configuration of SharePoint Products failed.  Configuration must be    performed before you use SharePoint Products.  For f
urther details, see the diagnostic log located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\1
5\LOGS\PSCDiagnostics_3_16_2016_4_10_1_696_703825228.log and the application event log.
```

Found this in the PSCDiagnostiscs log:

```
ERR          Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The upgrade command is invalid or a failure has been encountered.
Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException' was thrown.
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
```

In the Upgrade Log found this:

```
02/03/2016 01:08:55.13
OWSTIMER (0x25EC)
0x0F18  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade
SPHierarchyManager
ajyw3  INFO TranslationServiceApplication Name=Machine Translation Service
e0775b9d-a146-90af-0281-970e1f4a52c6
02/03/2016 01:08:55.13
OWSTIMER (0x25EC)
0x0F18  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade
SPHierarchyManager
ajyw3  ERROR Attempt to register null pointer at:    at   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.AddNextLevelObject(Object  current, Object next)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.Grow(SPTree`1 root, Boolean  bRecursing, SPDelegateManager delegateManager)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.Grow(SPTree`1 root,  SPDelegateManager delegateManager)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean  bRecurse)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean   recursively)     at   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object o, Boolean  bRecurse)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o,  Boolean bRecurse)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpgradeJobDefinition.Execute(Guid  targetInstanceId)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationServ

02/03/2016 01:08:56.06
OWSTIMER (0x25EC)
0x0F18  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade
SPHierarchyManager
ajyw3  INFO WordServiceApplication Name=Word Automation Services
e0775b9d-a146-90af-0281-970e1f4a52c6
02/03/2016 01:08:56.06
OWSTIMER (0x25EC)
0x0F18  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade
SPHierarchyManager
ajyw3  ERROR Attempt to register null pointer at:    at   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.AddNextLevelObject(Object  current, Object next)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.Grow(SPTree`1 root, Boolean  bRecursing, SPDelegateManager delegateManager)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.Grow(SPTree`1 root,  SPDelegateManager delegateManager)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean  bRecurse)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean  recursively)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object o, Boolean  bRecurse)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o,  Boolean bRecurse)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpgradeJobDefinition.Execute(Guid  targetInstanceId)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationServ


02/03/2016 01:08:56.06
OWSTIMER (0x25EC)
0x0F18  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade
SPHierarchyManager
ajyw3  INFO WordServiceApplication Name=Word Automation Services
e0775b9d-a146-90af-0281-970e1f4a52c6
02/03/2016 01:08:56.06
OWSTIMER (0x25EC)
0x0F18  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade
SPHierarchyManager
ajyw3  ERROR Attempt to register null pointer at:    at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.AddNextLevelObject(Object  current, Object next)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.Grow(SPTree`1 root, Boolean  bRecursing, SPDelegateManager delegateManager)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.Grow(SPTree`1 root,  SPDelegateManager delegateManager)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean  bRecurse)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean  recursively)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object o, Boolean  bRecurse)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o,  Boolean bRecurse)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpgradeJobDefinition.Execute(Guid  targetInstanceId)     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationServ

02/03/2016 01:13:18.15
OWSTIMER (0x25EC)
0x0F18  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade
SPUpgradeSession
aj0ur  INFO No context object
e0775b9d-a146-90af-0281-970e1f4a52c6
02/03/2016 01:13:18.15
OWSTIMER (0x25EC)
0x0F18  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade
SPUpgradeSession
aj0ur  ERROR Upgrade Timer job is exiting due to exception:     Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Upgrade completed with errors.   Review the upgrade log file located in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS\Upgrade-20160203-010218-680.log.  The  number of errors and warnings is listed at the end of the upgrade log file.      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.CheckPoint()     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.LogEnd()     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpgradeJobDefinition.Execute(Guid  targetInstanceId)
e0775b9d-a146-90af-0281-970e1f4a52c6
```

What I did so far:

- Test-SPContentDatabase: Found some orphaned sites and the deleted them
- Repair the Content Database:

  $database = Get-SPDatabase "Content_Database_Name"
  $database.Repair($false);
  $database.Update();

No problems found

- Check the Content Database:

  USE WSS_CONTENT
  GO

  ALTER DATABASE WSS_CONTENT SET SINGLE_USER
  GO

  DBCC CHECKDB ('WSS_CONTENT') WITH NO_INFOMSGS

No problems found

- Check orphan databases on web applications: No Orphan Databases found.

I Don´t  know if these errors are related to these services according to the Upgrade log:

TranslationServiceApplication

WordServiceApplication

I'm stuck on this! Is the third time I try to patch Sharepoint with the same results!

Plz your help and advice on what I need to do!

Thanks so much!

Comment: have you tried to run the config wizard via GUI instead of command line?

Answer (score 1):

How I fixed our SharePoint farm upgrade woes (Note: run all PowerShell (PS) commands in an elevated PowerShell window – *need 2 pre-opened windows*)

Turn off all the following services (you can do this in your first PowerShell window)

```
net stop SPTraceV4; net stop SPWriterV4; net stop SPAdminV4; net stop SPTimerV4; net stop w3svc
```

Manually stop both search services (in the services GUI on the SP server) – Note: SP 2010 only has 1 Search Service.
Run the following command in your second PowerShell window

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn command-line-upgrade-running -pv No
```

Flush the Config Cache follow [this blog post](http://itgroove.net/mmman/2013/05/21/clearing-the-sharepoint-configuration-cache/)
Run the following PowerShell in your second PowerShell window

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force
```

As soon as it reaches step #3 in the upgrade process, in the first elevated PS window, run the following PS

```
net start SPTraceV4; net start SPWriterV4; net start SPAdminV4; net start SPTimerV4; net start w3svc
```

Quickly manually start the two search services (in the Services GUI on the SP Server)
The upgrade process should complete successfully after this

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

clear configuration cache

1. Stop the Timer service. To do this, follow these steps:
2. Click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Services.
3. Right-click SharePoint 2010 Timer, and then click Stop.
4. Close the Services console.
5. On the computer that is running Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 and on which the Central Administration site is hosted, clickStart, click Run, type explorer, and then press ENTER.
6. In Windows Explorer, locate and then double-click the following folder:
7. `%SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\GUID`
8. Notes
9. The `%SystemDrive%` system variable specifies the letter of the drive on which Windows is installed. By default, Windows is installed on drive C.
10. The GUID placeholder specifies the GUID folder. There may be more than one of these.
11. The ProgramData folder may be hidden. To view the hidden folder, follow these steps:
12. On the Tools menu, click Folder Options.
13. Click the View tab.
14. In the Advanced settings list, click Show hidden files and folders under Hidden files and folders, and then click OK.
15. You can also simply type this directly in the path if you do not want to show hidden files and folders.
16. Back up the Cache.ini file. (Make a copy of it. DO NOT DELETE THIS FILE, Only the XML files in the next step)
17. Delete all the XML configuration files in the GUID folder (DO NOTE DELETE THE FOLDER). Do this so that you can verify that the GUID folders content is replaced by new XML configuration files when the cache is rebuilt. 
    Note When you empty the configuration cache in the GUID folder, make sure that you do NOT delete the GUID folder and the Cache.ini file that is located in the GUID folder.
18. Double-click the Cache.ini file.
19. On the Edit menu, click Select All.
20. On the Edit menu, click Delete.
21. Type 1, and then click Save on the File menu. (Basically when you are done, the only text in the config.ini file should be the number 1)
22. On the File menu, click Exit.
23. Start the Timer service. To do this, follow these steps:
24. Click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Services.
25. Right-click SharePoint 2013 Timer, and then click Start.
26. Close the Services console.
27. Note The file system cache is re-created after you perform this procedure. Make sure that you perform this procedure on all servers in the server farm.
28. Make sure that the Cache.ini file in the GUID folder now contains its previous value. For example, make sure that the value of the Cache.ini file is not 1.
29. Check in the GUID folder to make sure that the xml files are repopulating. This may take a bit of time.

Then try this 
`stsadm -o getproperty -pn command-line-upgrade-running if -pv No`

Then re-run configuration wizard:
`PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures`